Sonar lint plugin not showing the issues it found
[SonarLint Client RPC sequential executor] ERROR sonarlint - Error when handling a notification
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No log output configured
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.commons.log.LogOutputDelegator.lambda$log$0(LogOutputDelegator.java:40)

The following error pops up in log tab. The log tab also shows how many issues the plugin has found but the Current File tab remains empty showing no issues found.
Weirdly it works on the other system that I have and have added the plugin the same day.
Looking for any solution before I try reinstalling IDE itself.
I have already tried all permutations of uninstalling reinstalling plugin, deleting sonarlint cache, invalidate and restart IDE.

I'd suggest directly asking them on their Community Forum

Reinstalling has fixed it.
